# Overload ambiguity when passing R-value to function that takes L-value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have 2 overloaded functions - one takes an L-value, and the other takes an R-value.  The purpose is so that the function can be called like:

```
Obj obj;
foo(obj);
```

OR:

```
foo(Obj());
```

So, I write 2 overloaded functions:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T& v)
{
  /* ... function body code goes here ... */
}

template <class T>
void foo(T&& v)
{
    foo(v);
}

int main()
{
    foo(int(5));
}
```

The R-value overload merely needs to delegate to the L-value overload.  The way I understand it, once I'm in the body of the function, any use of `v` gives me an L-value reference, unless I specifically use `std::move` or `std::forward`.  So calling `foo(v)` within the R-value overload should automatically call the L-value version (rather than recursing.)

But, the compiler complains about ambiguity:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void foo(T&&) [with T = int]’:
test.cpp:305:12:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:299:2: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(int&)’ is ambiguous
```

I don't understand why this is ambiguous.  The call to `foo()` within the R-value overload should clearly call the L-value version.  So why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version: Try updating your compiler. Your version doesn't implement http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164 .

Your second template is a "perfect forwarding" template. Any function template parameter of type `T&&`, where `T` is a template parameter will deduce that template parameter to `X` (where `X` is the argument type) when the argument is an rvalue, and to `X&` if the argument is an lvalue.

In your case you passed an rvalue, so `T` was deduced to `Obj` (and `int` in your real code). If you would have passed a variable name or something else that is an lvalue, your second template would have the parameter type `Obj&` (T would be `Obj&`, and `&&` applied to such a type stays `Obj&`).

But the other template also has such a parameter type. So during overload resolution the conversion of the argument to the parameter is the same (perfect match), and another criteria needs to inspected, the *specifity* of the two templates, under the *partial ordering* rule. If one template is more specialized than the other template, then it will be chosen by the compiler. If there is no template more specialized than the other one, a final ambiguity is risen.

In this case, **the first template is more specialized than the second template**, and hence the compiler should call the first template finally.