# Is it possible to legally overload a string literal and const char*?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

Is it possible in C++11 to overload `const char*`'s and string literals (`const char[]`)?
The idea is to avoid having to call `strlen` to find the string length when this length is known already.

This snippet breaks on G++ 4.8 and Clang++ 3.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

template<typename T, int N>
void length(const T(&data)[N]) {
  printf("%u[]\n", N - 1);
}

template<typename T>
void length(const T* data) {
  printf("*%u\n", (unsigned)strlen(data));
}

int main() {
  length("hello");
  const char* p = "hello";
  length(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Error (Clang):

```
test2.cpp:16:3: error: call to 'length' is ambiguous
  length("hello");
  ^~~~~~
test2.cpp:6:6: note: candidate function [with T = char, N = 6]
void length(const T(&data)[N]) {
     ^
test2.cpp:11:6: note: candidate function [with T = char]
void length(const T* data) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Hacked a bit, and this appears to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

template<typename T, int N>
void length(const T(&data)[N]) {
  printf("%u[]\n", N - 1);
}

template<typename T>
void length(T&& data) {
  printf("*%u\n", (unsigned)strlen(data));
}

const char *foo() {
   return "bar";
}

int main() {
  length("hello");
  const char* p = "hello";
  length(p);
  length(foo());
  return 0;
}
```

Is this valid C++11? The string literal appears to overload on `T&&` when the array specialization is removed. What causes this ambigousness to be resolved, but not the one in the first code snippet?

Comment: Weird, I get [different behaviour](http://ideone.com/3vrQkG), and it depends on whether `char` is a template argument or not...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11625621/845568) answer has some relevant information about what's going on...

Comment: @KerrekSB: That is frankly uncomfortable :(

Comment: In the first snippet you can change the parameter of the second template to `const T* const&` and it should then work.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, @litb. I wonder why neither `boost::string_ref` nor the proposed `std::string_ref` provide a constructor from `const char(&)[]`

Comment: You have to overload `const T(&data)[N]` versus `const T* const & data` instead of `const T* data`. And of cause both functions must be template functions, otherwise deduction preorities would not be equal and a compiler will choose a not template function instead of a template one. For example, these won't work: `const char(&data)[N]` vs. `const char * const & data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, during overload resolution you have a perfect match requiring no conversion against an array to pointer conversion (which is in the category "lvalue transformation", along with lvalue to rvalue and function to pointer conversion). A difference that is only made by an lvalue transformation is not sufficient for overload resolution to pick a winner.

In the second case, during overload resolution, both functions have the exact same parameter type. Then partial ordering as the last resort finds that the second template would accept all arguments you ever pass to it, wheras the first template only accepts arrays. Therefor the first template in the second case is found more specialized and taken.

---

As for your other question - no, overloading specifically for string literals is not possible. You are always going to catch arrays of the same size along with them.