# Why does clang take a string literal as a pointer rather than an array?

Tags: c++, overloading, standards, string-literals

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(const char* arg)
{
    cout << "arg is a pointer" << endl;
}

template<size_t N>
void f(const char (&arg)[N])
{
    cout << "arg is an array." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f("");
}
```

My compiler is clang 3.8.

The output is:

> **arg is a pointer**

However, according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal),

> The type of an unprefixed string literal is const char[].

**Why does the overload resolution not behave as expected?**

Comment: Equivalent example, but abstracting away the template: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0nGenu5Ysj40wS8u

Comment: [Closely related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708307/is-it-possible-to-legally-overload-a-string-literal-and-const-char), possible dupe. What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does behave as expected, you just need to adjust your expectations ;-)

`const char[1]` and `const char (&)[1]` are different types.

The conversions to `const char*` (array-to-pointer conversion) and `const (&char)[1]` (identity conversion) are both considered exact matches, but a non-template is a better match than a template.

If you write a non-template size-specific overload,

```
void f(const char (&arg)[1])
```

you will get an error that the function call is ambiguous.

Comment: Too slow. :( For reference, the relevant standardese is in Table 12 in N4141

Answer (score 1):

@molbdnilo's answer is correct. To add one detail: Your intuition would be correct and the compiler would prefer to avoid the array-to-pointer conversion by calling the template. But lvalue transformations (lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer) are specifically ignored in overload ranking, according to [over.ics.rank] §13.3.3.2/3.2.1.

There is a [workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f7a6f3a05922751): add a fake `volatile` to restore the balance of overload preference. Just be sure to remove it by `const_cast` before using the parameter.